# why OCCI is crashing when calling to createConnection without exception?

Tags: c++, oracle, exception, occi

I am trying to run the next code inside a big program.

- In constructor init the Environment
- In the relevant function, simple call to the Env variable to make sure it is valid and functioning.
- call to the createConnection(). That's it. program vanish without even getting to the catch{} part.

1. The values of m_sUsername,m_sPassword,m_sDbname are valid (work with simple demo program).
2. Linking to **-lclntsh -locci_gcc53 -lclntshcore -lnnz21**
3. gcc details: **gcc (GCC) 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)**
4. Happens on both C++ 11 and c++ 17.
5. Oracle Instant Client 21_5
6. LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/OCCI/instantclient_21_5:/opt/product/oracle/19.0.0/client_1/lib:.:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib64
7. The other program (simple demo) works fine.

What can cause such situation?
**Any** idea is welcome.

````
OCCIDbs::OCCIDbs(){
 m_pOCCIenv = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT);
}

SqlDbConnection* OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection()
{
  if (!m_pOCCIenv) {
    LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection failed m_pOCCIenv is null");
    return nullptr;
  }
  LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection m_sUsername=%s, m_sPassword=%s, m_sDbname=%s",
    m_sUsername.c_str(), m_sPassword.c_str(), m_sDbname.c_str());

  oracle::occi::Connection* p = nullptr;
  try {  
    int majorVersion;
    int minorVersion;
    int updateNum;
    int patchNumber;
    int portUpdateNum;
    m_pOCCIenv->getClientVersion(majorVersion, minorVersion, updateNum, patchNumber, portUpdateNum);
    LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection() minorVersion =%d", minorVersion);
    
    LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection() m_sUsername=%s m_sPassword=%s m_sDbname=%s", m_sUsername.c_str(), m_sPassword.c_str(), m_sDbname.c_str());
    p = m_pOCCIenv->createConnection(m_sUsername, m_sPassword, m_sDbname);
    LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection()  after createConnection()");
  }
  catch (oracle::occi::SQLException& sqlExcp)
  {
    LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection Error=%d : %s", sqlExcp.getErrorCode(), sqlExcp.getMessage());
    return nullptr;
  }
  catch (std::exception& e) {
    LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection exception: %s", e.what());
    return nullptr;
  }
  LOGD("OCCIDbs::CreateConnectedConnection after createConnection()");```
````

Comment: You don't really mean "**Any** idea is welcome." There are a LOT of bad ideas out there.

Comment: One idea is to run it through a debugger... :)

Comment: *I am trying to run the next code inside a big program.* -- Then the issue is probably with the code you're not showing us, such as where, when, and how that `OCCIDbs` instance is created.  All you're showing us is class code, but if the instance of the class is not valid, none of that code you're showing us is valid.  To add, if a simple program works, then the issue must be the code you're not showing us that is different than the "simple program".

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how ever, to avoid impact of other code, I added the simple test call to 'm_pOCCIenv->getClientVersion()' to see that it is valid and functioning.
In any case, the only things in the code that are touching the OCCI objects are the one I wrote - constructor to init the m_pOCCIenv, and then my crashing call.
At first when I had this problem (in the test program), it appeared I didn't link all 4 files. after adding all 4, the test was working, but the above one didn't :-(.
So, maybe there are some flags/links/wrong files???